# When use Flutter epub_viewer to open EPUB file .... EpubViewer.locatorStream.listen() doesn' t work

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, epub

When use  Flutter epub_viewer to open EPUB file ....    EpubViewer.locatorStream.listen() doesn' t  work   just wanna save  this data to SharedPreferences  and then get ...

Or what should I do?

Code:

```
openEpuB() async {
  //var data = {
    //"bookId": "urn:uuid:d348699e-9011-4f87-901a-69754701bf83",
    //"href": "/OEBPS/Text/content_1.xhtml",
    //"created": 1608833000320,
    //"locations": {"cfi": "epubcfi(/0!/4/724/7:0)"},
    //"title": ""
  //};

  if (true) {
    EpubViewer.setConfig(
       identifier: 'androidBook',
      scrollDirection: EpubScrollDirection.VERTICAL,
      enableTts: false,
      allowSharing: true,
    );
    EpubViewer.openAsset('assets/4.epub',
       // lastLocation: data.isNotEmpty ? EpubLocator.fromJson(data) : null
);

    EpubViewer.locatorStream.listen(
      (event) async {
        print('WORk!!!!');
        // Get locator here
        saveDB(event);
      },
    );
  }
}
```